# Defining a `\subtitle` macro - `\reserved@e` undefined

Tags: expansion, expl3

I want to define a general-ish `\subtitle` macro that simply adds to the `\@title` macro set by the user-level `\title`.  Here is what I've got:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{xparse,expl3}
\makeatletter\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \subtitle { m }
  {
    \cs_set:Npx \@title
      {\@title\\[.5ex]\large#1}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff\makeatother

\title{A New Chapter}
\subtitle{In This Short Book}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Blah
\end{document}
```

This is supposed to define a document command `\subtitle` that takes one mandatory argument.
It then fully expands the current value of `\@title` and `\\[.5ex]\large#1`, setting this expanded value to `\@title`, effectively appending the subtitle to it.
Unfortunately, this raises the error

```
ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
\\  ->\let \reserved@e 
                       \relax \let \reserved@f \relax \@ifstar {\let \reserv...
l.12 \subtitle{In This Short Book}

--- HELP ---
TeX encountered an unknown command name. You probably misspelled ...
```

Why am I getting this error and, more importantly, how might I fix it?

Comment: Are you aware that a second use of `\subtitle` adds another line and the use of `\title` will overwrite any previous subtitles?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I am, but thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Whatever your final decision for code is, please place it as argument to `\AtBeginDocument`; you'll know why when one of the users of your class will be asking you about the disparition of a subtitle (you'll certainly find somebody putting `\subtitle` before `\title`). Wouldn't a syntax such as `\title[Subtitle]{Title}` be better?

Comment: @egreg Very good point about users possibly having `\subtitle` before `\title`; the optional argument syntax is much nicer, actually.  I didn't put too much thought into it, as this document class is only for a team of around five people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `x` stands for “exhaustive expansion” (please see the [manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/l3kernel/interface3.pdf#page=13), p. 2 or 13 for that). This seems like a bad idea with `\\` and `\large`.

I’d simply expand the `\@title` once and append the rest:

```
\expandafter \cs_set:Npn \expandafter \@title \expandafter
   { \@title \\[.5ex] \large #1 }
```

The `\tl_put_right:**` (or `\appto` from `etoolbox`) macros do this without `\expandafter`s.

I’m using `:cn { @title }` here but obviously you can just use `:Nn \@title` with correct catcodes (i.e. in a package).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{xparse,expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \subtitle { m }{
  \tl_put_right:cn { @title } % or \tl_put_right:Nn \@title with \makeatletter
    { \\[.5ex] \large #1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\title{A New Chapter}
\subtitle{In This Short Book}
\subtitle{And another line?}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Blah
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd *really* like to avoid the use of `\expandafter`; this is `expl3` after all.  I didn't think about the issues with ``\\``/`\large` though, I was focussed on `\@title` when I was writing my macro.  ``\\``/`\large` are definitely the source of the problem, but how might I resolve this without `\expandafter`?

Comment: Also, my apologies about `@`; I moved this into a test file where it had been in a class file.  Thanks for pointing it out, though!

Comment: @SeanAllred Is `\noexpand` allowed? I’m no 3 expert so I wouldn’t use it in the first place. ;) (You need two `\`` for ``\\`` in comments.)

Comment: I'd still like an `expl3` solution, but if nobody pokes in with one, this will work. :)

Comment: @SeanAllred The `\tl_put_right:**` macros are the equivalent of `\appto`. See my update.

Comment: Indeed, `\@title` is clearly equivalent to an `expl3` `tl` rather than a function, so really `\tl_put_...` is the right choice. Of course, you should really only be storing the text and dealing with the design by altering `\@maketitle`, but that's another question!

Comment: Besides `\@title` being a variable -- the `\expandafter`'s could be replaced with an `o` type argument: `\cs_set:Npo \@title { \@title \\[.5ex] \large #1 }`